# Only show last overlay per slide after presentation's end

Tags: beamer, overlays

Using `\only`, `\onslide` and so on in LaTeX beamer produces several pages per slide in the *.pdf document.

I am wondering if there is a shortcut or something to remove those 'preliminary' slides after finishing the presentation (or maybe reaching a specific slide) and only show the last page per slide.

This might be useful after a presentation's end and people asking questions to specific slides. I find it quite annoying clicking through the whole presentation and each slide rebuilds step by step instead of just showing the final version of a slide.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the viewer [pdfpc](https://pdfpc.github.io/) ([github](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc)) for that.
Since version 4.0.7 it supports:

> - A user can now skip already viewed overlays (and jump to the full
>     slide directly)

It also has an overview feature to switch directly to the needed slide and many other nice features.

[image]

Currently it works with Linux and Windows 10 (with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)).

Comment: Maybe you could post this idea also as a workaround for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303495/36296

Comment: @samcarter Ok, I added a comment there.