# Customize frame navigation symbol in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, navigation

So I'm preparing a beamer presentation with lots of overlays and, in case people ask me to go back and forth, I want to have the option of skipping them mid presentation. The frame navigation button more or less does this, but the forward button goes to the first overlay of the next frame when I actually want it to go to the last overlay. Is there any way to achive this?

Also ideally I would like to do this only with the keyboard instead with on-screen buttons. That is I would like the arrows to move within overlays and, lets say, pg dwn and pg up to move between frames, but I would be happy with just the first thing.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473252/134144 might be interesting.